# How to split object into array of object depends on custom key of object

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
{
    'S-First Name': 'Seif ',
    'S-Last Name': 'Ali',
    'S-Gender': 'Male',
    'S-Date Of Birth': 2011-06-24T21:59:51.000Z,
    'S-Nationality': 'Egyptian',
    'S-National ID': 21106250100531,
    'S-Grade': 'G5',
    'S-Class': 'B',
    'S-URL Photo': 'mb23thud',
    'FG-First Name': 'Ali',
    'FG-Last Name': 'Ahmed',
    'FG-Relation': 'FATHER',
    'FG-Gender': 'Male',
    'FG-Date Of Birth': 1981-08-08T20:59:51.000Z,
    'FG-Nationality': 'Egyptian',
    'FG-National ID': 28108090100531,
    'FG-Email': 'jojo@gmail.com',
    'FG-Phone Number': '00201016606666',
    'SG-First Name': 'Aya',
    'SG-Last Name': 'Adel',
    'SG-Relation': 'MOTHER',
    'SG-Gender': 'Female',
    'SG-Date Of Birth': 1997-10-24T21:59:51.000Z,
    'SG-Nationality': 'Egyptian',
    'SG-National ID': 29710250103561,
    'SG-Email': 'aya@gmail.com',
    'SG-Phone Number': '00201016605555'
}
```

split on S- and FG- and SG-

```
{

  student: {
    'S-First Name': 'Seif ',
    'S-Last Name': 'Ali',
    'S-Gender': 'Male',
    'S-Date Of Birth': 2011 - 06 - 24 T21: 59: 51.000 Z,
    'S-Nationality': 'Egyptian',
    'S-National ID': 21106250100531,
    'S-Grade': 'G5',
    'S-Class': 'B',
  },
  first guardian {
    'FG-First Name': 'Ali',
    'FG-Last Name': 'Ahmed',
    'FG-Relation': 'FATHER',
    'FG-Gender': 'Male',
    'FG-Date Of Birth': 1981 - 08 - 08 T20: 59: 51.000 Z,
    'FG-Nationality': 'Egyptian',
    'FG-National ID': 28108090100531,
    'FG-Email': 'jojo@gmail.com',
    'FG-Phone Number': '00201016606666',
    'SG-First Name': 'Aya',
  },
  secound guardian {
    'SG-First Name': 'Aya',
    'SG-Last Name': 'Adel',
    'SG-Relation': 'MOTHER',
    'SG-Gender': 'Female',
    'SG-Date Of Birth': 1997 - 10 - 24 T21: 59: 51.000 Z,
    'SG-Nationality': 'Egyptian',
    'SG-National ID': 29710250103561,
    'SG-Email': 'aya@gmail.com',
    'SG-Phone Number': '00201016605555'
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

To split the **object** into an **array** of **objects** based on custom key prefixes, you can use the [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) method to create an array of key-value pairs for the original object, then uses [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to group the entries by **prefix**.

The `determinePrefixOnKey` function takes a `key` as its argument and returns a `string` that represents the prefix of that key.

**Code:**

```js
const data = {
  'S-First Name': 'Seif',
  'S-Last Name': 'Ali',
  'S-Gender': 'Male',
  'S-Date Of Birth': '2011-06-24T21:59:51.000Z',
  'S-Nationality': 'Egyptian',
  'S-National ID': 21106250100531,
  'S-Grade': 'G5',
  'S-Class': 'B',
  'FG-First Name': 'Ali',
  'FG-Last Name': 'Ahmed',
  'FG-Relation': 'FATHER',
  'FG-Gender': 'Male',
  'FG-Date Of Birth': '1981-08-08T20:59:51.000Z',
  'FG-Nationality': 'Egyptian',
  'FG-National ID': 28108090100531,
  'FG-Email': 'jojo@gmail.com',
  'FG-Phone Number': '00201016606666',
  'SG-First Name': 'Aya',
  'SG-Last Name': 'Adel',
  'SG-Relation': 'MOTHER',
  'SG-Gender': 'Female',
  'SG-Date Of Birth': '1997-10-24T21:59:51.000Z',
  'SG-Nationality': 'Egyptian',
  'SG-National ID': 29710250103561,
  'SG-Email': 'aya@gmail.com',
  'SG-Phone Number': '00201016605555'
};

const determinePrefixOnKey = (key) => {
  switch (key) {
    case 'S':
      return 'student';
    case 'FG':
      return 'first-guardian';
    case 'SG':
      return 'second-guardian';
    default:
      return '';
  }
};

const result = Object.entries(data).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
   const prefix = determinePrefixOnKey(key.split('-')[0]);
   if (!acc[prefix]) {
      acc[prefix] = {};
   }
   acc[prefix][key] = value;
   return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution if I understand what you try to achieve.

```js
const initial = {
    'S-First Name': 'Seif ',
    'S-Last Name': 'Ali',
    'S-Gender': 'Male',
    'S-Date Of Birth': '2011-06-24T21:59:51.000Z',
    'S-Nationality': 'Egyptian',
    'S-National ID': '21106250100531',
    'S-Grade': 'G5',
    'S-Class': 'B',
    'S-URL Photo': 'mb23thud',
    'FG-First Name': 'Ali',
    'FG-Last Name': 'Ahmed',
    'FG-Relation': 'FATHER',
    'FG-Gender': 'Male',
    'FG-Date Of Birth': '1981-08-08T20:59:51.000Z',
    'FG-Nationality': 'Egyptian',
    'FG-National ID': '28108090100531',
    'FG-Email': 'jojo@gmail.com',
    'FG-Phone Number': '00201016606666',
    'SG-First Name': 'Aya',
    'SG-Last Name': 'Adel',
    'SG-Relation': 'MOTHER',
    'SG-Gender': 'Female',
    'SG-Date Of Birth': '1997-10-24T21:59:51.000Z',
    'SG-Nationality': 'Egyptian',
    'SG-National ID': '29710250103561',
    'SG-Email': 'aya@gmail.com',
    'SG-Phone Number': '00201016605555'
}

const parseRecord = (input) => {
  const result = {
    student: {},
    firstGuardian: {},
    secondGuardian: {},
  }
  
  Object.keys(input).forEach(key => {
    if (key.toUpperCase().startsWith('S-')) {
      result.student[key] = input[key];
    } else if (key.toUpperCase().startsWith('FG-')) {
      result.firstGuardian[key] = input[key];
    } else if (key.toUpperCase().startsWith('SG-')) {
      result.secondGuardian[key] = input[key];
    }
  })
  
  return result;
}

const parsed = parseRecord(initial);

console.log(parsed)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.entries()` to get array of keys & values and run `reduce` method to accumulate your data into new object.The `key` & `value` of the current item is extracted using destructure and passed as the `reduce` args. The new `rootKey` is set using the current key prefix and helper object `rootKeys`. The `subObj` is created using key & value of the current item. Next, the `subObj` is merged to the accumulated object using `rootKey` and spread operator.

```js
    const data = {
      'S-First Name': 'Seif',
      'S-Last Name': 'Ali',
      'S-Gender': 'Male',
      'S-Date Of Birth': '2011-06-24T21:59:51.000Z',
      'S-Nationality': 'Egyptian',
      'S-National ID': 21106250100531,
      'S-Grade': 'G5',
      'S-Class': 'B',
      'FG-First Name': 'Ali',
      'FG-Last Name': 'Ahmed',
      'FG-Relation': 'FATHER',
      'FG-Gender': 'Male',
      'FG-Date Of Birth': '1981-08-08T20:59:51.000Z',
      'FG-Nationality': 'Egyptian',
      'FG-National ID': 28108090100531,
      'FG-Email': 'jojo@gmail.com',
      'FG-Phone Number': '00201016606666',
      'SG-First Name': 'Aya',
      'SG-Last Name': 'Adel',
      'SG-Relation': 'MOTHER',
      'SG-Gender': 'Female',
      'SG-Date Of Birth': '1997-10-24T21:59:51.000Z',
      'SG-Nationality': 'Egyptian',
      'SG-National ID': 29710250103561,
      'SG-Email': 'aya@gmail.com',
      'SG-Phone Number': '00201016605555'
    };


 const rootKeys = { S: 'student', FG: 'first guardian', SG: 'second guardian' };

 const result = Object.entries(data).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
  const rootKey = rootKeys[key.split('-')[0]];
  if (!rootKey) return acc;
  const subObj = { [key]: value };
  acc[rootKey] = { ...acc[rootKey], ...subObj };
  return acc;
}, {});;


console.log(result);
```